# Jupyter notebook can't find kernel when run through /etc/rc.local

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, torch, jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter Notebook server on an EC2 instance with python2 (default) and ITorch kernels. Everything works fine when run through SSH command line.

The problem is that when I try to make this run at startup, the notebook server can't find ITorch kernel. I does work fine for python notebooks though. The error I get is a window saying

```
Kernel not found
I couldn't find a kernel matching iTorch. Please select a kernel: (python2)
```

What I did was adding this line to `/etc/rc.local`

```
 /home/ubuntu/anaconda2/bin/jupyter-notebook --JupyterApp.config-file=/home/ubuntu/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py &> /dev/null &
```

The notebook server apparently runs fine. This is from the system log

```
ip-172-31-20-152 login: [32m[I 12:20:51.073 NotebookApp][0;10m Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/ubuntu/notebook
[32m[I 12:20:51.076 NotebookApp][0;10m 0 active kernels 
[32m[I 12:20:51.078 NotebookApp][0;10m The Jupyter Notebook is running at: https://[all ip addresses on your system]:8888/
[32m[I 12:20:51.081 NotebookApp][0;10m Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

These are the only lines I modified in my config file

```
# Configuration file for jupyter-notebook.
c = get_config()
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = u'/home/ubuntu/notebook'
c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/home/ubuntu/certs/mycert.pem'
c.NotebookApp.keyfile = u'/home/ubuntu/certs/mycert.key'
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.password = u'<password>'
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
```

Comment: The ITorch kernel is probably set up for your user, and when the system runs it, it's a different user. Run `jupyter kernelspec list` to see where the kernels are, and if ITorch is under your home directory, copy it to `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/`

Comment: That did it. So simple! I guess I need to improve my unix skills. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Thomas K comment solved it:

"The ITorch kernel is probably set up for your user, and when the system runs it, it's a different user. Run `jupyter kernelspec list` to see where the kernels are, and if ITorch is under your home directory, copy it to `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/`".